# How can I sort a given record in different running times - O(n) and O(nlogk), where k is the distinct values for a sequence n with key-value pairs?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, hashmap, time-complexity

My given sequence looks like this

```
<product, quantity>

<milk, 2>, <bread, 3>, <eggs, 3>, <sugar, 2>, <apples, 4>, <berries, 4>
Here I have my n value as 6 and k as 3 (3 distinct values - 2, 3, 4).
```

My sorted sequence should be like this. Sorted in increasing order of key-values

```
<milk, 2>, <sugar, 2>,  <bread, 3>, <eggs, 3>, <apples, 4>, <berries, 4>
```

What algorithms can I use to sort this in two running times? 1. O(n) 2. O(nlogk)

Comment: This sounds like homework, What algorithms did you come up with and what where their time complexities?

Comment: You posted (and deleted) [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728658/how-can-i-sort-a-given-record-in-two-different-ways-on-and-onlogk-where-k) 1 hour ago. Why did you post this duplicate instead of improving the other one?

Comment: @Henry I tried with hash map and tree map, but I am having a tuff time understanding how the run-time complexity would be O(nlogk) when I am using a tree map. I am self-learning algorithms and am trying to solve some problems that I came across in the books.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I am quite new to the stackoverflow community. I wanted to improve the quality of the question. That is why I decided to take it down. I will remember going forward to edit the same question. Thank you for your valuable suggestions. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Gokkul You should update the question with what you have tried. Stackoverflow works best when you tell what you tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started learning algorithms so correct me if im wrong.
I think we can use redblack tree or treemap for sorting the key,value pair in running time of O(n) and then traverse through the key-value pair to display the distinct values of k in running time of O(log k). So total running time would for this algorithm would be n * log k =O(n log k).

Comment: `we can use redblack tree or treemap for sorting the key,value pair in running time of O(n)` What does "use redblack tree or treemap" mean here? You mean inserting values?

Comment: @gokkul: I think for this question this would be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965132/java-sort-hashmap-by-value?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @GauravSingh: Treemap for getting the unique elements without any duplicates and to get the sorted order

Comment: For Treemap (and [red-black trees](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) in general), O(NlogN) to insert N values, and O(N) to traverse.